# How to fix header and sidebars in CSS grid when using tocbot

Tags: javascript, css-grid, scrollspy

I am using CSS grid. I need to fix the header area and both sidebars (left and right) so that only the content pane scrolls. I am using tocbot to generate the scrollspy kind of output in the right sidebar. In the codepen below, the right sidebar links get highlighted if you see the code inspector but because the entire page is scrolling, you cannot see it in page view. How can I achieve this so that all but content is fixed and always visible and the right sidebar works with highlighting current heading. I have even removed the footer to see if that works but no go. If I use max-height to fix the view, tocbot/right-sidebar doesn't highlight toc entries anymore.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 4;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background-color: white;
}

.header-top-left {
  grid-column: 1/12;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  max-height: 5vh;
}

.header-top-right {
  grid-column: 10/13;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  max-height: 5vh;
}

.header-bottom-left {
  grid-column: 1/10;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  max-height: 5vh;
}

.header-bottom-right {
  grid-column: 10/13;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  max-height: 5vh;
}

.ht-sidebar {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.ht-content {
  grid-column: 3/11;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.onthispage {
  grid-column: 11/13;
  grid-row: 3/4;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tocbot/4.4.2/tocbot.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header-top-left">Header Top Left </div>
    <div class="header-top-right">Header Top Right </div>
    <div class="header-bottom-left">Header Bottom Left </div>
    <div class="header-bottom-right">Header Bottom Right </div>

    <div class="ht-sidebar">Sidebar</div>

    <div class="ht-content js-toc-content">Content

      <h1 id="1"> Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales
        leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis
        vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.
        <p>

          <p>Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing, commodo quis, gravida id, est. Sed lectus. Praesent elementum hendrerit tortor. Sed semper lorem at felis.
            Vestibulum volutpat, lacus a ultrices sagittis, mi neque euismod dui, eu pulvinar nunc sapien ornare nisl. Phasellus pede arcu, dapibus eu, fermentum et, dapibus sed, urna.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus
            hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo.
            Suspendisse potenti.</p>
          <h1 id="2"> Heading 2</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales
            leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.
            <p>

              <p>Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing, commodo quis, gravida id, est. Sed lectus. Praesent elementum hendrerit tortor. Sed semper lorem
                at felis. Vestibulum volutpat, lacus a ultrices sagittis, mi neque euismod dui, eu pulvinar nunc sapien ornare nisl. Phasellus pede arcu, dapibus eu, fermentum et, dapibus sed, urna.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis.
                Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
              <h1 id="3"> Heading 3</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero
                sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel,
                dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.
                <p>

                  <p>Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing, commodo quis, gravida id, est. Sed lectus. Praesent elementum hendrerit tortor. Sed semper lorem
                    at felis. Vestibulum volutpat, lacus a ultrices sagittis, mi neque euismod dui, eu pulvinar nunc sapien ornare nisl. Phasellus pede arcu, dapibus eu, fermentum et, dapibus sed, urna.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
                    elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh.
                    Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
                  <h1 id="4"> Heading 4</h1>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero
                    sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.
                    <p>

                      <p>Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing, commodo quis, gravida id, est. Sed lectus. Praesent elementum hendrerit tortor. Sed semper
                        lorem at felis. Vestibulum volutpat, lacus a ultrices sagittis, mi neque euismod dui, eu pulvinar nunc sapien ornare nisl. Phasellus pede arcu, dapibus eu, fermentum et, dapibus sed, urna.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
                        adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc
                        tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
                      <h1 id="5"> Heading 5</h1>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor
                        libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.
                        <p>
    </div>

    <div class="onthispage js-toc">tocify Output </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tocbot/4.4.2/tocbot.min.js"></script>


    <script>
      tocbot.init({
        // Where to render the table of contents.
        tocSelector: '.js-toc',
        // Where to grab the headings to build the table of contents.
        contentSelector: '.js-toc-content',
        // Which headings to grab inside of the contentSelector element.
        headingSelector: 'h1, h2, h3',
        // For headings inside relative or absolute positioned containers within content.
        hasInnerContainers: false,
      });
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on CSS grid to be able to solve this and finally switched to Flexbox. No issues at least for now.